# FOSS inventory management systems?

Tags: untagged

Investigating inventory management software and was hoping to get some recommendations! Tested OCS so far and am almost hoping that there's an alternative that is extensible and has an API.

------- UDPDATE --------

I want an IMS that can be integrated into our existing systems: cobbler, puppet, powerdns, etc. So we don't have certain host data in one database and partially duplicated in another database. I would like for all provision, configuration, and management systems to drink from the data graciously updated within an IMS.

I'm kind of amazed that an IMS doesn't exist in any notable web framework. One that could be integrated along side puppet and other favorites. :(

Comment: Can you please update the question and elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: They all either suck and/or are limited to Windows :(

Comment: There aren't any good ones. I'm trying to get together some python developers to help me make a new one.  Perhaps we should somewhere, make a list of functional requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Open-AudIT.
Works on Windows, Linux, etc. GPL licensed. Based on PHP/MySQL.

http://www.open-audit.org

Answer (score 1):

GLPI, which stands for "Gestionnaire libre de parc informatique".

http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en

> You can use it to build up a database with an inventory for your
>   company (computer, software, printers, …). It has enhanced
>   functions to make the   daily life for the administrators easier, like
>   a job tracking system with    mail-notification and methods to build a
>   database with basic information about your network-topology.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Spiceworks?

http://www.spiceworks.com/free-pc-network-inventory-software/

Comment: Sure, this satisfies the "F" (beer) requirement, but not the "OSS" part.